# Beer fermenting too cold?

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature

[My first brew](http://www.brewtoad.com/recipes/kontra-smash-ipa) is currently fermenting on its 6th day. I just checked the temperature and it was quite a bit lower than what I initially thought. The temperature in the room is 12'C (54'F) and the brew had almost the same temperature. I just did a test with my hydrometer and it measured to 1020, which translates to around 1019 with temperature adjustments.

I have used the White Labs WLP001 California Ale Yeast.

Is this brew spilled or can I do anything to save it?

Comment: It's also worth to note that temperature outside dropped from +10'C to -10'C and I did not measure room temperature before the drop because I assumed it had normal room temperature, 20'C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to raise the temperature of the beer back up to around 68F/20C, and give it a gentle shake to try to get the yeast resuspended.

Note that you will see airlock activity - this doesn't necessarily mean fermentation has started, but that the higher temperature is causing the gas in the headspace to expand and exit the airlock. Leave it for another 3-5 days and then check the gravity to see if fermentation started. With any luck, it should be complete and you hit FG.

Comment: My thermometer was wrong. Just bought a new one today and measured ~18'C (~64'F) in the room and 16.5'C (~62'F) in the beer. Does the gentle shake you suggested still apply or should I just leave it?

Comment: The shake won't do any harm other than potentially dislodge some of the "braun hefe" stuck to the sides of the fermentor.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to ferment way below optimal temp range. However yeast can do his work at the 54F. What's the OG of your brew? Do you perceived bubbling on the airlock? Any sign of krauzen?

Saludos

Comment: OG 1059. It seems the bubbling in the airlock has stopped. Krauzen?

Comment: @Meindert - You're asking quite a lot of questions in your answer - it's best to ask these questions as comments, and then answer once you've got the clarification.

Comment: Kraeusen (sic. 'krauzen') is the foam that appears on top of the beer during fermentation.

Comment: Yeap, that's me trying to collect as much information as possible in order to have a much better picture of the situation... Your approach to answer question might also work.